# Automatically updating parts of a text in Pages

Tags: pages

I have a document in Pages. This document contains text. In this text there are three dates:

> Bla bla bla 24.12.2022 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla. And more bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 24.12.2022. And yet more bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 23.01.2023 bla bla.

The first two dates are the same. The third date is 30 days after the first date (December 24th + 30 days = January 23rd).

What I want is that when I change the first date, the second and third dates update automatically. That is, when I change the first date to 25.12.2022, for example, the second date updates to 25.12.2022, too, and the third date updates to 24.01.2023.

Is that possible in Pages? I know it can be done in table cells, but I want to do it in running text.

I'm using Pages version 13.0 (7036.0.126) under macOS 13.3.1 (22E261).